# Making a Table in PHP

Tags: php, html

basic question is im trying to make a table similar to this

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_caption_test

for my webpage: http://lamp.cse.fau.edu/~mcuervo5/p6/

in my php file for "name" & "votes"

by making the table for my boy table and girl table all border up and separated neatly

but it my first time using margin and padding to make the space neat & been having a lot of trial and error here & cant seem to solve the problem

tried to replace this:

```
$myTable = "<table>
```

with this:

```
$myTable = "<table style="margin: 5px; border: 1px; border-color: black;">
```

but got error code :(. 
You can right click "inspect" the page or take it from here from my php code so far. Thanks guys if you can help me with this

```
    <?php
require_once './php/db_connect.php'; // Will call this php file
?>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
```

Just added this to make the border line

```
      <style>
          table, th, td 
          {
    border: 2px solid black;
          }</style>
```

End new edit

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Maundy | Comming Soon Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Free Bootstrap Theme by BootstrapMade.com">
    <meta name="keywords" content="free website templates, free bootstrap themes, free template, free bootstrap, free website template">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans:400,400italic,300italic,300|Raleway:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>


    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>


    <body>

<div class="col-lg-12">



<form method="post" action="index.php">
        <label>Enter Name for Baby:</label>
        <input type="text" name="baby_name" />
        <label>Select Gender:</label>
        <select name="gender">
            <option value="B">Boy</option>
            <option value="G">Girl</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Sumbit!" />
    </form>

</div>



<?php 
if (isset($_POST['gender'])&& isset($_POST['baby_name']) )
    {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $val_input = $_POST['baby_name'];


// Add two rows to the table
$selectStmt = 'SELECT  `Votes`
FROM  `Free_Names` 
WHERE  `Gender` =  \''.$gender.'\' AND `Name` = \''.$val_input.'\';';

$result = $db->query($selectStmt); //query the "select" statement and update the result
if($result->num_rows > 0) { //if has a results

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //updates the statments

$UpdateStmt = 'UPDATE `Free_Names`  
SET `Votes` = '.($row["Votes"] +1).'
WHERE `Gender` =  \''.$gender.'\' AND `Name` = \''.$val_input.'\';';
$db->query($UpdateStmt); //this will run, but wont work

}


}


else
{

$insertStmt = 'INSERT INTO `Free_Names` (`Name`, `Gender`, `Votes` )' . PHP_EOL
            . '  VALUES (\''.$val_input.'\',\''.$gender.'\',1);'; 

$db->query($insertStmt); //


}

}

?>




<?php
// Get the rows from the table, and \\ for single quote to show up
$selectStmt = 'SELECT  `Name` ,  `Votes` 
FROM  `Free_Names` 
WHERE  `Gender` =  \'B\'
ORDER BY  `Votes` DESC 
LIMIT 5';
?>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
```

It around here is the table for the names

```
     BOY NAMES
</div>
<?php
$result = $db->query($selectStmt); //query the "select" statement and store the result
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $myTable = "<table>
  <thead>
  <tr><th>Name</th>
  <th>votes</th></tr>
  </thead><tbody>";        

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myTable.= "<tr>
        <td>".$row["Name"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Votes"]."</td>
        </tr>";                       

    }
    $myTable.= "</tbody></table>";
    echo $myTable;
} else {
    echo '        <div class="alert alert-success">No Results</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
      </div>



<?php
// Get the rows from the table, and \\ for single quote to show up
$selectStmt = 'SELECT  `Name` ,  `Votes` 
FROM  `Free_Names` 
WHERE  `Gender` =  \'G\'
ORDER BY  `Votes` DESC 
LIMIT 5';
?>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
  GIRL NAMES
</div>
<?php
$result = $db->query($selectStmt); //query the "select" statement and store the result
if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $myTable = "  <table>
  <thead>
  <tr >
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>votes</th>
  </tr>
  </thead><tbody>";        

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myTable.= "<tr>
        <td>".$row["Name"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Votes"]."</td>
        </tr>";                       

    }
    $myTable.= "</tbody></table>";
    echo $myTable;
} else {
    echo '        <div class="alert alert-success">No Results</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use single quotes to define your variable. Your HTML attributes close the double quote early. `$myTable = '<table style="margin: 5px; border: 1px; border-color: black;">'` But as explained in the current answer, I'd recommend not using inline styles.

Comment: so this is what the code look like https://scontent-mia1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/17879976_1429751863744212_2702799190078009747_o.jpg?oh=14fb203bd590bc5acf42fd22261c83c9&oe=59597566 Im trying to separate the table boy and girl into the center of the page

Comment: Mate, your question is about generating a table in PHP. Now if it's about how to format it, that's a different story. Ask a new question about CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just use the W3Schools example. When it comes to cellpadding, add the style to `<td>` . When it comes to cell margins, add the style to `<table>` using `border-spacing` :

```
td{
  padding: 12px 6px;
}
table{
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
  padding: 12px 6px;
}
table{
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <caption>Monthly savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do I put this in term of the php file above? in the HTML portion? thanks

Comment: Add it inside your CSS file, or put it inside a `<style>` tag.

Comment: OK i did this 

table, th, td 
          {
    border: 2px solid black;}
      </style>

which got me my brackets BUT YOUR CODE:

 border-spacing: 10px;          
    padding: 12px 6px

didnt work :(, did i do something work cause the spacing wont work

Comment: so this is what the code look like https://scontent-mia1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/17879976_1429751863744212_2702799190078009747_o.jpg?oh=14fb203bd590bc5acf42fd22261c83c9&oe=59597566

Im trying to separate the table boy and girl into the center is my goal